# Query returns empty, expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to show my profile user's info, but when I test it gives me an empty result;

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, string given

I tested if the mysql query its working, and it does, because it's showing my   `echo 'Id user: '.$id_user;` so, I don't know what's going on here.

```
$id_user = $_SESSION["id_usr"];
$consulta = 'SELECT user,name,password,city FROM web_users WHERE id_user=" . mysqli_escape_string($id_user) . "';
$resultado = $mysqli->query($consulta);
echo 'OK<br>';
echo 'Id user: '.$id_user;
/*if ($resultado->affected_rows == 1){*/
   $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta);
   echo '
      <div class="form_title">User:</div>
      <div class="form_content">'.$row["user"].'</div><br><br>
      <div class="form_title">Name:</div>
      <div class="form_content">'.$row["name"].'</div><br><br>
      <div class="form_title">Password:</div>
      <div class="form_content">'.$row["password"].'</div><br><br>
      <div class="form_title">City:</div>
      <div class="form_content">'.$row["city"].'</div><br><br>';
  /*}
else{
   $row = array();
   echo "<br>Empty Result";
}*/
```

[Here you have what is showing :D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mM5I9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your php has syntax error, you can't use `'` when you need php code in your query mysqli_escape_string($id_user) like you did, but you can update to :

```
$consulta = 'SELECT user,name,password,city 
FROM web_users WHERE id_user=\'' . mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$id_user) .'\'';
```

or

```
$consulta = "SELECT user,name,password,city 
FROM web_users WHERE id_user='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$id_user) ."'";
```

where `$con` is your connection object:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
```

Comment: @Aleix Gallet Segarra, the first param for  mysqli_real_escape_string function is  connection object.

Answer (score 0):

As per your screen shot, you are getting `UserID = 1` so you can use your query as like that:

```
<?php
    $consulta = 'SELECT user,name,password,city 
    FROM web_users WHERE id_user='.mysqli_escape_string($id_user);
    $result = $conn->query($consulta);
?>
```

Now regarding this issue:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result

```
// you can use like that:
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        //your stuff
    }    
} 
else 
{
    echo "0 results";
}
?>
```

**Issue in your code:**

Actually you are mixing `Object Oriented` and `Procedural` method together and also with wrong variable.

Suppose, if you want to use `mysqli_fetch_assoc` with procedural way like:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta);
```

**Than**, note that `$consulta` is not returning the resource id, `$consulta` is equal to your query that you have write in a string.

Comment: Don't use shot tags `<?` ... they're deprecated and won't work by default in PHP7.

Comment: @worldofjr: thank you brother ... i will research for this.. i didnt checked.. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are some errors within your script kindly check them to work it properly please replace your query with this one and let me know if this help

```
<?php
     $id_user =  mysqli_escape_string($_SESSION["id_usr"]);
     $consulta = "SELECT user,name,password,city FROM web_users WHERE id_user='$id_user'";
     $resultado = $mysqli->query($consulta);
     echo 'OK<br>';
     echo 'Id user: '.$id_user;

     $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
?>
```

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the result set from your query and loop through any results. Additionally, you're using a single quote string which doesn't work over multiple lines.

You don't need to `echo` everything out though. You can just drop out of PHP processing and re-enter it when you need a variable.

```
$resultado = $mysqli->query($consulta);
echo 'OK<br>';
echo 'ID user: ' . $id_user;
while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc())
{
   ?>
      <div class="form_title">User:</div>
      <div class="form_content"><?=$row["user"];?></div><br><br>
      <div class="form_title">Name:</div>
      <div class="form_content"><?=$row["name"];?></div><br><br>
      <div class="form_title">Password:</div>
      <div class="form_content"><?=$row["password"];?></div><br><br>
      <div class="form_title">City:</div>
      <div class="form_content"><?=$row["city"];?></div><br><br>
   <?php
}
```

Additionally, you're using `mysqli_real_escape_string()` inside a string without properly leaving the string parsing. I wouldn't actually try to clean inputs by escaping the strings anyway; prepared statements are a much better idea ...

```
$consulta = 'SELECT user,name,password,city FROM web_users WHERE id_user = ?';
$stmt = $con->prepare($consulta);
$stmt->bind_param('i', $id_user);
$stmt->execute();

$resultado = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc())
{

}
```

*Note: You should protect against SQL injection. Take a look at [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/3899908)*

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
$consulta = 'SELECT user,name,password,city FROM web_users WHERE id_user="' . mysqli_escape_string($id_user) . '" ';
$resultado = mysqli_query($con,$consulta);


$con->your connection string.
```